# How to display real-time ticker info from coinbase pro websocket subscription (python)

Tags: python, api, websocket, coinbase-api, cryptocurrency

I'm new to websockets and using web APIs and have been a bit confused as to how to extract real time information from the coinbase pro websocket.

Here is my code for creating a new websocket and subscribing to the ticker channel, I have already authenticated with my account and API key:

```
wsClient = cb.WebsocketClient(url="wss://ws-feed.pro.coinbase.com",
                                 products=ticker,
                                 channels=["ticker"])
```

But then, I'm not really sure what to do. Is there a function I call to print the information I want? I have tried indexing with `['price']` or using `.__getattribute()` but have been unsuccessful. The closest other post I have found [is this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62302757/coinbase-pro-web-socket-get-the-current-price-for-a-currency). But it seems like my websocket doesnt have a `.on()` function. The coinbase pro docs [simply list the data returned by the subscription](https://docs.pro.coinbase.com/#the-ticker-channel), but I'm unsure as to how to actually access and print it.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Edit:
I have figured out that `cb.WebsocketClient.start(wsClient)` starts printing the results in JSON to console. Am I able to put this into a file and then parse it? Is there a faster way than writing to a JSON file and parsing it?